# Unity inspector not showing variables of custom component that inherits from a built-in class

Tags: unity, c#, inheritance

I made a class `AdvancedButton` that inherits from the built-in class `Button`:

```
public class AdvancedButton : Button
{
    public bool advancedTest = false;
}
```

The Unity inspector only shows the variables of `Button`, but not the variable `advancedTest`. Is this normal or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have System.Serializable attribute added to your inheriting class?

Comment: The Unity API is based on composition over inheritance. You usually don't inherit from the standard Unity classes, like you would in Unreal or Godot. You create your own components inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` instead which interact with the standard components by calling their public methods and properties. Can you tell us what you are *actually* trying to do? We might be able to tell you how to do that in a more idiomatic way.

Comment: I'd suspect that the Button type has a custom editor that overrides the default inspector logic for it. You might need to write one for your subclass too, so that Unity finds and uses that one instead of the base class's when looking for the right inspector-drawing logic.

Comment: @Nikaas ... I just added System.Serializable, but it didn't make it work.

Comment: @Philipp ... Thank you for clearifying this. I'm not trying to achieve anything special by making AdvancedButton. I'm just new to Unity and wanted to see what can be done and what not.